# Convergence and divergence behavior of recurrence relations

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

In our lecturer's notes which can be seen below. We have a nonconstant $b$ values while we are studying $Y_t = A * b^t - c $ kind of problems. Is it a typo where she meant to put $Y_t$ on the x-axis or am I missing something.

[image: Lecturer note]

And also I do not understand how the $f_1$ function in the image following converges because its trajectory is under the $45^o$ line. Isn't $lim_{x->\infty} \sqrt{x}$ is under the $45^o$ line but it is not convergent AFAIK.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps something on fixed point interactions can help you to understand the second picture.

Comment: @JoséCFerreira I see now, there is a convergence of $Y_t$ to the point where these lines cut each other. Do you have any idea about the first picture? Any answer would be more than appreciated.

Comment: It is a representation to the function $y(t)=ab^t-c$, when $t$ is a natural number.